# How can I get a count of the number of Backers in my database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have this Lambda expression that returns a list of campaigns with their associated services, backers and orders.

I need to get a total number of backers for the campaign.  Each campaign can have multiple services and each service can have multiple backers.

My current code:

```
Campaign campaign = db.Campaigns.Include(c => 
                          c.Services.Select(s => 
                              s.Orders.Select(o => o.Backers)))
                      .Where(c => c.CampaignID == id)
                      .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not calling `Count()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`?

Comment: I am using all the values that this query is providing.  I also need just a simple count of the Orders placed for this campaign.

Answer (score 1):

- `Campaigns` has many `Services`
- `Services` has a property `Orders`
- `Orders` has many `Backers`

Is what I'm seeing.  So:

```
int count = db.Campaigns.Find(id)
                          .Services
                            .SelectMany(s => s.Orders.Backers)
                            .Count();
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ProjectName.Order> does not contain a definition for Backers and no extension method ProjectName.Backers accepting a first argument of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ProjectName.Order> can be found

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalBackers = campaign.Services.SelectMany(x => x.Orders.Select(y => y.Backers.Count)).Sum();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.